# Download a true type font file( .ttf) hosted on a service and use it at runtime

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a True type font (.ttf) file hosted on a service. I obtain it in the form of a byte array. I need to set the font in that file during run-time.

I am facing the problem on Windows Phone 7 and the service used is a simple WCF service which provides the .ttf file as a byte-array.

This is what I have done till now but it doesn't seem to work.. :

```
        IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        string fontPath = string.Empty;
        string ss = string.Empty;

        IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("foo.ttf", System.IO.FileMode.Create, file);
        fs.Write(e.Result.byteArray, 0, e.Result.byteArray.Length);
        fs.Dispose();

        fs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("foo.ttf", FileMode.Open, file);
        ss = fs.Name + @"#My Font";
        textBlock1.FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily(ss);
```

Comment: Why not deploy the font with your application?

Comment: I need to customize the solution extensively and provide a client provided true-type font instead of releasing the package all over again.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain a bit more about why you think it doesn't seem to work.  What's the failure mode?  Does a call fail?  Does an exception get thrown?  Does the code execute to completion but not behave as you'd expect?

Comment: The code executes without any exception. But the font doesn't reflect on the target textblock where I am trying to set it. It shows the text in the default font. 
On the other hand, if I make the same font file as a part of the project, then the font is properly rendered.

PS: The context of this problem is Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. There is a **FontSource** property of a textblock which has a constructor which takes a **STREAM** as parameter. The **.ttf** file can be read from the Isolated Storage in the form of a **stream**.

The FontFamily can then be set as any of the fonts present in the .ttf font file.

The code snippet is as follows:

```
void ttlHost_FileStreamingCompleted(object sender, TTL_Host.FileStreamingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        FontSource mySource;
        byte[] MyFont;

        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fs = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("foo.ttf", System.IO.FileMode.Create, file))
        {
            fs.Write(e.Result.byteArray, 0, e.Result.byteArray.Length);
        }

        MyFont = e.Result.byteArray;

        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = file.OpenFile(""foo.ttf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                mySource = new FontSource(reader.BaseStream);
                myTextBlock.FontFamily = new FontFamily("My Font");
                myTextBlock.FontSource = mySource;
            }
        }

        myTextBlock.Text = "Changed Font";
}
```